# SQL Server 2000 Stored Proc bombing for no apparent reason

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

On the if it bombs or some error always - any help would be so greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_LetsWork
  (@MYID int,  @ThisDate Datetime)
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  DECLARE @intErrorCode int,  
          @QStartDate datetime, 
          @QEndDate datetime 

  SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR

  --DATEPART(mm, @ThisDate) BETWEEN  1 and 3 -- test both options
  BEGIN
    IF @ThisDate BETWEEN '01/01/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@ThisDate)) 
                         AND '03/31/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(@ThisDate))  
    RunQuarter:
        SELECT * 
        FROM qryAR 
        WHERE CID = @MYID 
          AND (paiddate >= @QStartDate 
          AND paiddate <= @QEndDate)
        --ORDER BY paiddate ASC

        GO
        -- GOTO RunQuarter
  END
  GO

  SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR

  IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO ErrHandler

  RETURN 0

ErrHandler:

  RETURN @intErrorCode

GO
```

Comment: Dude, you MUST give us the error(s) if you really expect help...

Comment: Error 170: Line 35; Incorrect Syntax near )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `GO` halfway in the stored proc.

[`GO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) is not SQL: it tells client tools like SSMS where a batch ends

So the error is *after* `paiddate <=@QEndDate)` because this is the end of the stored proc because of `GO`: there is no matching `END` for the `BEGIN` above this

It isn't "bombing" on execution because it isn't being created...

Comment: @Kris: please vote up and/or accept using the arrows and tick to the left if this solves your problem and you're happy with the answer. Ta